# Adjacent Pixels differ by more than 2, possible assignments of grey levels of two adjacent pixels out of 64 possible combinations?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

## I recently came across following question, and I am not sure if I understand the question to solve it. Can someone here possibly help me understand it?

A black and white computer graphics display is divided int an array of pixels.
Each of the pixels can take on one of eight gray levels ranging from 0 to 7. 
In order to prevent sharp discontinuities of shade, the system enforces the rule that,the gray levels of adjacent pixels cannot differ by more than 2. 
How many of the 64 possible assignments of grey levels of two adjacent pixels satisfy the rule?

Possible answers:

- 24
- 32
- 34
- 40
- 64

I wish to understand the basics of solving this problem. :)
Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to count (or figure out a way to calculate) how many combinations of 2x 8-level colors you can create that differ by 0, 1 or 2. Since they say "of the 64 possible", it means assigning two equal colors are inside those combinations.

Comment: Break it down into sub-problems. How many combinations can you create where the colors are equal? How many combinations can you create where the colors differ by exactly 1? How many combinations can you create where the colors differ by exactly 2?

Comment: Note that with the choices given, they count both A+B and B+A as two distinct combinations (ie. the combinations are counted both ways, so the combination 0,1 counts as 1, and the combination 1,0 counts as an additional 1 giving 2. Now all you have to do is figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have 2 pixels, every pixel can be any number from 0 to 7 (that's 8 different possibilities). There are 8x8 = 64 combinations in total. However, your problem gives an additional limitations, that the pixel values cannot be too far apart, which renders some of the combinations valid and some of the combinations invalid.

You just have to count how many are valid.

---

For example, take the first pixel of value `0` -- the other pixel cannot be any value from 0 to 7, just only 0, 1 and 2 (because 3-0 > 2). Apply the similar chain of the reasoning for the other possible values.

---

Well, answering the comment. You have 3 possible combinations for values `0` and `7`, 4 possible combinations for values `1` and `6`, the rest have 5 possible combinations: 2 * 3 + 2 * 4 + 4 * 5 will give you the answer =)

Comment: I think your answer explained what I was missing. I failed to spot the obvious that there are 2 pixels, each with 8 possibilities, and hence, 64 combinations. I am now more curious to understand, how would I mathematically solve it without having to plot it, as my next step. any inputs are appreciated. cheers !

Comment: thank you. what I meant was, is there a way, to mathematically, maybe using some formula, to get the answer, instead of visualizing / plotting it on a paper and going up from there? e.g. if I had 0-10 bits instead of 0-7, the plotting becomes less efficient in such case.

Answer (score 2):

As it is on understanding:

```
 01234567
0***.....
1****....
2*****...
3.*****..
4..*****.
5...*****
6....****
7.....***
```

5*8-2*3

Or on diagonals: 8 + 2*7 + 2*6 ...

Comment: Thank you. Picture speaks 1000 words. Can you please elaborate the 5*8 - 2*3 mathematics? If I am not mistaken, its (remaining 5 states out of 8 combinations) - (2 pixels with 3 combinations) ? is that correct?

Comment: The range -2 till +2 gives 5, 8 different values: 5*8. For 0 and last value -2, for 1 and penultimate -1, so 5*8 - 2*(2+1).

Comment: You could also shove the two `.` triangles together, and see that its area is 5*(5+1) = 30, where 5 = 8-3. Hence `*` area is 8²-5*6. That is easier as more regular for calculation in mind